# Can I access Laravel development server remotely?

Tags: laravel

I have been following the Laravel tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_installation.htm).

It says:

> Start the Laravel service by executing the following command.

```
php artisan serve
```

Following this, I get the following response:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

I am running an ubuntu instance in google cloud and do not want to install a desktop environment and go through vnc and all that stuff in order to confirm Larvael installed correctly.

My first instinct was to append :8000 to the IP address of the server I am using, (i.e. http://35.246.167.37:8000)

It didn't work so I entered a new firewall rule to allow tcp and udp traffic on port 8000.  That didn't work either.

```
This site can’t be reached 35.246.167.37 refused to connect.
```

Is it possible to access the laravel development server remotely in order to confirm a successful install?

Comment: I use `ngrok` for that. - https://ngrok.com/ - Very useful tool

Answer (score 1):

But if you have setup firewall rules on your server it may be dropped?

Try running it natively rather than through artisan, and note **example #6** on this page

You can make the web server accessible on port **8000** to any interface with:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the host and port options `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to open a firewall port

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

And now you have to put this

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

It works for me =D !

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand artisan runs the built-in php development server under the hood. For the latter the documentation clearly says that to access that server remotely you need to specify the host as `0.0.0.0`. So, to get that running with the `php artisan` command you need to execute:

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Of course, any other available port can be specified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check incoming port 8000 and all outgoing port opened.

And maybe you can try use port 80 too

```
php artisan serve --port=80
```

Comment: We use Google Cloud too, but we configured Apache with Document Root to /public